# Find out what is using SQL installations on a Windows Server

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have taken over a server that has tons of SQL Server related bits installed, and as far as I know, there are no applications on the server requiring the use of SQL.

There are different SQL Server tools, versions etc. all installed. How can I find out what is using each version of SQL or if they are even being used at all?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking at:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to shut all of the SQL server components down, or block the port (1433) at the firewall, and see if anyone complains or anything breaks.

I don't mean to be glib, and I realize that that might not be an acceptable solution in a production environment, but if no one seems to know of any reason to run those services, it might be a reasonable way to find out, especially at off hours.

Comment: Would all versions etc. above use that same 1433 port?